# Javascript 'map' not supported in IE WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c, internet-explorer, d3.js, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use d3 ([www.d3js.org](http://www.d3js.org)) with the Microsoft WebBrowser control from C.  d3 uses the Javascript 'map' method from Array.  This is new in IE since version 9.  While the IE10 browser is able to handle d3 quite nicely, the WebBrowser control does not.

I'm calling document.write() through third party code over which I have no control.  It's ole_ie.c and you can find it on the web (see 'DisplayHTMLStr').  If I have to, I can abandon it but I'd rather not.

Here is a test string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" ></meta>
<title>Get documentMode!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>document.documentMode</h2>
<p>
<script>
/*@cc_on @*/
document.write(document.documentMode);
alert(@_jscript_version);
var x = ['a'].map(function(a) {});
</script>
<p>
</body>
```

This works fine when run from a file, but when sent to the WebBrowser (and you dismiss the dialog) you get "Object doesn't support property or method 'map'".

I have set the registry key FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to various values (and I see it being read); most recently 0x2711.  I've also tried various flavors of X-UA-Compatible.  Through experiment I have achieved documentMode's of 5, 7 or 8.  @_jscript_version is 10.  MSHTML.DLL version is 10.0.9200.16750.  I'm using Win7-64.

Can anyone get this to work?

Comment: Try also `document.write(document.compatMode)`, what do you see for `compatMode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move to IE11.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a pollyfil :

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: The MDN code seems a bit sub–optimal to me. *Array.prototype.map* and strict mode were both introduced in ES5, so it's very unlikely that a browser that dosen't have *map* will have strict mode. Also `void 0` is just an obfuscated way of writing `undefined`, is it really *that* important to save 3 characters? There are others…

Comment: Well, that solved the 'map' problem.  Now it doesn't understand 'forEach'.

Comment: Here you have a collection of pollyfils, including one for the forEach : https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js

Comment: Which requires 'createElementNS'.

Comment: Here is another collection including shim for 'createElementNS' https://github.com/shawnbot/aight/blob/master/aight.js the collection is build for D3 / IE8 -> https://github.com/shawnbot/aight

Comment: Which throws an error.  I see code which says 'throw "Sorry, this browser does not support namespaces"'.